# I have dynamically generated 2 <tr> and I want to get the data of the <tr> I click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The Question might be confusing but this is the exact situation..

I have dynamically generated few  ( as per data fetched from database) and now I want to allow the user to select one of the radio buttons and I want to capture the details of the row clicked so please check my code and assist

My ajax code

```
$.ajax({
                data: data,
                url: url,
                type: 'POST',
                datatype: 'JSON',
                success: function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    var result = $.parseJSON(response);
                    var count = result.length;
                    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                        var $row = $("<tr><input type='hidden' id='"+ result[i].objId + "' value='"+ result[i].objId+"'><td><input type='radio' name='dbRadio' id='dbRadio'></td><td>" + result[i].name + "</td><td> Murgency Global Network</td><td>" + result[i].number + "</td><td>" + result[i].city + "</td><td> 0.5 Km</td></tr>");
                        $('table.queriedResponder > tbody:last').append($row);
                    }
                    console.log($row);
                }
            });
```

my radio button detection code

```
 $('input[name=dbRadio]').change(function(){
           console.log('clicked');
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an instance of `this` and get the `closest` `tr`:

```
$('input[name=dbRadio]').change(function(){
    console.log($(this).closest("tr"));
});
```

Of course, if this handler isn't being hit, it's probably because your rows are being added dynamically - so delegate the handler:

```
$('table.queriedResponder').on('change', 'input[name=dbRadio]', function() {
    console.log($(this).closest("tr"));
});
```